# What is the etymology of 'oojiboo'?

Tags: etymology

[Oojiboo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=oojiboo):

> a thing whose name one forgets, does not know, or prefers not to mention

Since I don't have access to the OED, can someone tell me its etymology and whether it's commonly used nowadays?

Comment: I haven't heard it in the UK.

Comment: I don't know. I have not downvoted.

Comment: Can suspended users award bounties?

Answer (score 4):

OED:

> **Etymology:**  Apparently < oojah *n.* + an arbitrary element *boo.* Compare jigaboo *n., icky-boo adj.* at icky *adj.* and *n.* Derivatives, hickboo n., etc.

Examples from 1918, 1925, 1933.

Answer (score 2):

The term '[**oojah**](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/727783/oojiboo)' is soldiers' slang, and was known as a 'gadget' during WWII according to the Dictionary of service slang, compiled by Park Kendall (1944)

A theory on the origin of [**ooja-ka-piv**](http://www.word-detective.com/back-m2.html):

> "Widget" is a bit more recent than "gadget," means roughly the same
>   thing, and may be simply an alteration of the word "gadget." One
>   theory, in fact, holds that "widget" arose in the Royal Navy as a
>   contraction of "wifflow-gadget," also known as a "hook-me-dingy" or
>   "ooja-ka-piv." All those terms, like "gadget" itself, were invented by
>   sailors who had momentarily forgotten what to call a particular piece
>   of equipment.

& the term "**Oojieoo**" -notably a song title found in a 1910 Catalog of copyright entries

> **Oojieoo**. The hardest worked word. Signified anything, its nearest
>   equivalent being "gadget." Once I heard this dialogue :
>
> —Lorry driver: "Sorry, Flight, but in the fog a fellow passed me on
>   the wrong side and carried away my oojiboo."
>
> Flight Sergeant: "That's the second side-lamp you've done in this
>   week."
>   -Origins and meanings of popular phrases & names, including those which came into use during the great war, by Basil Harg ave. [1932]

Answer (score 0):

According to the OED the term has different spellings and its origin remains obscure.

***Oojah, oojahslang*** (Also oojar, ujah)
***of uncertain origin.***

> - A substitute expression used to indicate vaguely a thing of which the speaker cannot at the moment recall the name, or which he does not care to specify precisely; a ‘what-you-may-call it’, gadget.
> - ***1917 W. Muir Observations of Orderly xiv. 229*** ‘Oojah’, anything. > - ***1925 Fraser & Gibbons Soldier & Sailor Words 215*** Oojah (also Ooja-ka-pivi), a substitute expression for anything the name of which a speaker cannot momentarily think of, e.g. ‘Pass me that h-m, h-m, oojah-ka-pivi, will you?’
> - ***1930 Wodehouse Very Good, Jeeves! i. 25***  ‘All you have to do,’ I said, ‘is to carry on here for a few weeks more, and everything will be oojah-cum-spiff.

(OED)

According to the following source the most used form is ***oojah***.

[oojah](http://www.seadict.com/en/en/oojah) or [oojiboo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oojiboo) or oojamaflip:

> - noun informal used when one cannot think of or does not wish to use the name of something.
>
> *ORIGIN early 20th cent.: of unknown origin.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oojah,%20oojiboo,%20oojamaflip&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,oojah;,c0): oojah.